# Continuous Chef FC016 FoodCritic Error

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, lwrp

I am trying to test creation of my own LWRP. I keep getting the following error message, even though I have tried specifying my *default_action* in three different ways.

```
Error Message: FC016: LWRP does not declare a default action: mycookbook/resources/eapi_deploy.rb:1
```

First Try

```
actions :deploy, :undeploy, :debug
default_action :debug
```

Second Try

```
default_action :debug
actions :deploy, :undeploy, :debug
```

Third Try

```
actions :deploy, :undeploy, :debug

def initialize(*args)
  super
  @action = :debug
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the LWRP Chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/lwrp_custom_resource.html), your first try looks correct. I used Berkshelf to create a new cookbook (`berks cookbook mycookbook`), and created resources/test.rb and pasted in:

```
actions :deploy, :undeploy, :debug
default_action :debug
```

And I don't get a foodcritic error. Do you happen to have more than resource defined? Are you sure the foodcritic warning is pointing to the resource you're showing us?

For what it's worth, I then removed the `default_action` line, and re-ran foodcritic, and I get FC016 like you do.

Comment: thanks @Martin , there was another compilation error in my resource file that caused this message . Thanks